# Deriving Gauss-Bonnet Gravity (Or just higher order corrections)

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, spacetime-dimensions, gauss-bonnet

I have been working for some time now on deriving the equations of motion (EOM) for the [Gauss-Bonnet Gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Bonnet_gravity), which is given by the action:

$$\int d^D x \sqrt{|g|} (R^2-4R_{ab}R^{ab}+R_{abcd}R^{abcd}).$$

I've tried for some time to derive the first-order variation with respect to $\delta g_{ab}$. I have always been stuck with the derivation for the $\delta (R_{ab}R^{ab})$ component. Suppose I have only a Riemann tensor that contains **only constants**, 
\begin{align*}
\delta(R_{ab}R^{ab}) & = (\delta R_{ab})R^{ab} + (\delta R^{ab})R_{ab} \\
    & = (\delta R_{ab})R^{ab}+ \delta(R_{ecfd}g^{ac}g^{bd})g^{ef}R_{ab} \\
    & = (\delta R_{ab})R^{ab}+ (\delta R_{ecfd})g^{ac}g^{bd}g^{ef}R_{ab} + (\delta g^{ac}) R_{cd}g^{bd}R_{ab}+(\delta g^{bd})R^{a}{}_{d}R_{ab}\\&\quad+ (\delta g^{ef}) R_{e}{}^{a}{}_{f}{}^{b}R_{ab}.
\end{align*}

This however, gives us:
\begin{align*} & = - (\delta g^{hi}) R_{ichd}R^{cd}  
+( \delta g^{hi}) R_{hcid}R^{cd} + 2(\delta g^{ac}) R_{cd}R_{a}{}^{d} \\
     & = 2(\delta g^{ac}) R_{cd}R_{a}{}^{d}. 
\end{align*}

The correct answer as we know it, is $2R^{ab}R_{acbd}\delta g^{cd}$.

Comment: Just curious, what is your goal in this work? I have worked on this in the past so I am first trying to get a better feel for the overall scope of your work.  Also, you say that "as we know ..." the answer is ..., are you referring to some reference in the literature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to resolving this is as follows. First, don't assume that the Riemann tensor is a constant:

\begin{align*}
\delta(R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}) & = [-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta} + 2 R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}R_{\nu\alpha} + \square R_{\mu\nu} -\nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\mu}R_{\nu}{}^\alpha - \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\nu}R_{\mu}{}^\alpha + g_{\mu\nu} \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}R^{\alpha\beta}]\delta g^{\mu\nu} \\
& = [-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta} + 2 R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}R_{\nu\alpha}-((\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\alpha}+ \square R_{\mu\nu} -[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\alpha])R_{\nu}{}^\alpha \\&\quad+(\nabla_{\nu}\nabla_{\alpha}-[\nabla_\nu,\nabla_\alpha])R_{\mu}{}^\alpha) + g_{\mu\nu} \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}R^{\alpha\beta}]\delta g^{\mu\nu}\\
& = [-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta} + 2 R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}R_{\nu\alpha}+ \square R_{\mu\nu} \\&\quad-\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu R + [\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\alpha]R_{\nu}{}^\alpha + [\nabla_\nu,\nabla_\alpha]R_{\mu}{}^\alpha + \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} \square R]\delta g^{\mu\nu}\\
& = [-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta} + 2 R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}R_{\nu\alpha}+ \square R_{\mu\nu} -\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu R  +2(-R_{\alpha \nu}R^{\alpha}{}_\mu \\& \quad+ R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta})+ \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} \square R]\delta g^{\mu\nu} \\
& =  [-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta} -\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu R + \square R_{\mu\nu} +2R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}+ \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} \square R]\delta g^{\mu\nu}.
\end{align*}

Dropping the constant terms, we arrive at $ -\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R_{\alpha\beta}R^{\alpha\beta}+2R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}$, including the term from varying $\sqrt{|g|}$. The problem with the previous solution is in the transition from the second to the third line, because one still has to vary the metric, and one should vary everything first without assuming constants, since the commutator of the covariant derivatives do not commute. I think the problem arises because even if the Riemann tensor is a constant, the metric that comes up with it does not necessarily (e.g. $S^2$) that it is constant, so we can't just say $\delta R_{abcd} = 0$, and we have to check the parts of it.

Comment: Your variations disappeared on the right hand side...

Comment: Oh yes... I dropped them all for typographic clarity... You can add a $\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ to all of them on the right. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 5):

You can derive the desired expression in the following way:

\begin{align}\delta(R_{ab}R^{ab})
&=\delta R_{ab} R^{ab}+R_{ab}\delta R^{ab}\\
&=\delta R_{ab}R^{ab}+R_{ab}\delta R_{cd}g^{ca}g^{db}\\
&=\delta R_{ab}R^{ab}+R^{cd}\delta R_{cd}\\
&=2R^{ab}\delta R_{ab}\\
&=2R^{ab}\delta(R_{cadb}g^{cd})\\
&=2R^{ab}\delta(R_{acbd}g^{cd})\qquad\mbox{(by symmetry of the Riemann tensor)}\\
&=2R^{ab}\delta R_{acbd}g^{cd}+2R^{ab}R_{acbd}\delta g^{cd}.
\end{align}
In the last line, the variation of the Riemann tensor vanishes due to the assumption that it is constant, leaving us with

$$\delta(R_{ab}R^{ab})=2R^{ab}R_{acbd}\delta g^{cd}.$$

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for the solution, but I think it is problematic. I've managed to resolve this actually and am writing both my solution and correction to yours below.

Comment: I thought that the assumption was that the Riemann tensor was a constant? If it is not, of course my solution is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but I believe that one needs to deal with the variations with an arbitrary Riemann tensor first. Then can one set the condition that the Riemann tensor is a constant. If one does not do it, there are terms dropped, which nevertheless come from the commutators of the covariant derivatives. 

Also, I'm not entirely sure if your transition from the second line to the third line is correct. The variation should be $\delta (R_{cd} g^{ca}g^{db}) = (\delta R_{cd})g^{ca}g^{db}+R_{cd} (\delta g^{ca})g^{db} + R_{cd} g^{ca}(\delta g^{db})$, so I believe two more terms are missing.

Comment: If we assume that it is constant, we can drop the variation from the beginning. Furthermore, the transition you mention is correct. After all, we vary with respect to the metric with lower indices.

Comment: The reason I don't think the transition is correct, and maybe I am wrong, is that the metric with lower indices remains related to the metric with upper indices (as it is a function of the metric with upper indices). As such, the variation must take them into account.

Comment: You are right that they are related, but when using the variational principle, one treats the metric and its inverse as independent fields.

Comment: I agree, but isn't everything done so far a variation with respect to upper indices (as you wrote in the final answer). In that case, then you should keep the variation in the upper indices, if those are what you want to collect in the end.

Comment: No. Until the last line, I have varied with respect to lower indices. This is not an inconsistency, as both methods (either lower or upper) should give the same result