# Variation of a part of the Gauss-Bonnet-Invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, curvature, variational-calculus

I am trying to calculate the variation of the Gauss-Bonnet-Invariant, which is given by
$R_{GB} = R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R^{2}$,
with respect to the metric tensor $g^{\mu\nu}$.
I already calculated the $R^2$ part from $R_{GB}$ which gives me

$\delta\big(R^2\big) = 2RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}$.

For the variation of the Ricci-Tensor part i get:
\begin{align}
\delta\Big(R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}\Big) &= R_{\mu\nu}\delta R^{\mu\nu}+ R^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu} = R^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu} + R_{\mu\nu}\delta\Big(g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma} R_{\rho\sigma}\Big) \\
&= R^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}+ R_{\mu\nu}\Big(R_{\rho\sigma}g^{\mu\rho}\delta g^{\nu\sigma}+R_{\rho\sigma}g^{\nu\sigma}\delta g^{\mu\rho}+g^{\nu\sigma}g^{\mu\rho}\delta R_{\rho\sigma}\Big)\\
&=  2R^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}+ 2R_{\mu\nu}R^\rho_\nu\delta g^{\mu\nu} \\
&= 2R_{\mu\nu}R^\rho_\nu\delta g^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
Is it right to assume that the $2R^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}$ part vanishes?

Comment: Well, you can't just assume it vanishes, you have to prove it. Why do you think it vanishes? (Btw I'm not saying whether it does or doesn't, off hand I don't know but suspect not, but there is a well known answer you should get for the equations of motion)

Comment: I haven't gone through the calculation but the final two lines you have $\nu$ repeated three times. Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86021/deriving-gauss-bonnet-gravity-or-just-higher-order-corrections?rq=1